# MYSQL: How to find the MIN of this 2 dimensional problem?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying now for 4 hours to get a solution of this two dimensional problem:
I have this table:

[image: ProblemTable]

Now I would like to find for each row the minimum of the Values in the columns.

The output of the MySQL Query should be the row and column name ( which fields are linked to each Value in the table) .

I would be happy if one could open my eyes.

EDIT:
Here is my LEvenshtein-Matching Table: (DEMO)

```
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tLDResults`;
     CREATE TABLE `tLDResults` (
       `BIOGRAPHYTITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       `recid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `BIOTIrecid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
       `LD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       `ScopusTI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`recid`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

     -- ----------------------------
     -- Records of tLDResults
     -- ----------------------------
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('ABC', '1', '420', '1', 'ABCs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('ABC', '2', '420', '13', 'KUIJHKJJKJKKs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('BCD', '3', '421', '2', 'ABCs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('BCD', '4', '421', '13', 'KUIJHKJJKJKKs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('KLKKLK', '5', '422', '6', 'ABCs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('KLKKLK', '6', '422', '9', 'KUIJHKJJKJKKs');
```

THANKs

Comment: Doyou really have 2 columns called klk AND is there a limited known number of columns and if so what is it

Comment: @P.Salmon yes dublicates of col/rows are allowed and the number of col/rows are dynamically. I tried with a inner join . But without of success.

Comment: I'm not clear how this data hangs together. IF you have 2 columns called KLK and 1 is min and the other is max in a row would you still want KLK in your result. Also if you have many rows with the same name would there be a requirement to fetch the min KLK even if the KLK is on a different row?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have edit it with my Demo Table. It is a matrix with the Levenshtein Distance of two strings. Now I would like to find the best match of these two set of Strings (=TItles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX(BIOGRAPHYTITLE)  is for the case that there are multiple minimums

```
SELECT 
    t1.ScopusTI,
    MAX(BIOGRAPHYTITLE)    
FROM tLDResults t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(`LD` + 0) MINLD,ScopusTI FROM tLDResults GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
GROUP BY ScopusTI
```

SEe example fiddle
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tLDResults`;
     CREATE TABLE `tLDResults` (
       `BIOGRAPHYTITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       `recid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `BIOTIrecid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
       `LD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       `ScopusTI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`recid`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

     -- ----------------------------
     -- Records of tLDResults
     -- ----------------------------
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('ABC', '1', '420', '1', 'ABCs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('ABC', '2', '420', '13', 'KUIJHKJJKJKKs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('BCD', '3', '421', '2', 'ABCs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('BCD', '4', '421', '13', 'KUIJHKJJKJKKs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('KLKKLK', '5', '422', '6', 'ABCs');
     INSERT INTO `tLDResults` VALUES ('KLKKLK', '6', '422', '9', 'KUIJHKJJKJKKs');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
t1.ScopusTI,
    MAX(BIOGRAPHYTITLE)

FROM tLDResults t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(`LD`+0) MINLD,ScopusTI FROM tLDResults GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
GROUP BY ScopusTI;

| ScopusTI      | MAX(BIOGRAPHYTITLE) |
| ------------- | ------------------- |
| ABCs          | ABC                 |
| KUIJHKJJKJKKs | KLKKLK              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: THANKS a lot! Great doee - now I learned was I have made wrong. But why do I not geht the LD=9 for the second row??

Comment: that's because  LD isn't a number but a text, i corrected my answer

Comment: THANKS a lot! I always had this 13 too in my solutions, so that was the reason . I have to do it as int.